# Error while running the solr:server_win rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, sunspot-solr

I am getting the following error while running the rake command for solr:start_win. I hve also installed sunspot_rails gem.
Please help us on this.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\trunk>rake solr:start_win
(in C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/trunk)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: and.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" production Solr started successfully on 8982.
```

Comment: To run solr you need to have java properly installed in your system have you tried using bundle exec rake solr:start_win

Comment: I have installed java and also tried with "bundle exec rake solr:start_win". This time I am getting the following error at my console.

bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
Could you please give me some other solution for this?

Comment: I am using this command to start solr in my ubuntu system  rake sunspot:solr:start also which ruby and rails versions are you using?